# overloading the divison operator to beable to divide large numbers using strings in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to divide strings called BigInts with large numbers . I wrote my code so that I first convert the number on the right to a longlong int called divisor. This was a method that I found online to divide strings. The problem is that I cant store enough digits in long long int divisor to divide numbers with more than 32 digits. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? I have really been struggling a lot with this assignment.

```
 BigInt operator/( BigInt left, BigInt right)
{

    long long int divisor = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < right.data.size(); i++)
    {

       divisor = divisor*10 + right.data[i] - '0';

    }


    BigInt ans;
    ans.data.pop_back();
    BigInt empty;

    int idx = 0;
    long long int temp = left.data[idx] - '0';
    while (temp < divisor)
        temp = (temp * 10) + (left.data[++idx] - '0');


    while (left.data.size()  > idx)
    {
        ans = ans + (temp / divisor);

        temp = (temp % divisor) * 10 + left.data[++idx] - '0';
        if(temp == 0)
        {
            ans.data.push_back('0');
        }
    }

    if (ans.data.length() == 0)
        return empty;

    if(left.isNegative && right.isNegative)
    {
        ans.isNegative = false;
    }
    if(!left.isNegative && right.isNegative)
    {
        ans.isNegative = true;
    }
    if(left.isNegative && !right.isNegative)
    {
        ans.isNegative = true;
    }
    if(!left.isNegative && !right.isNegative)
    {
        ans.isNegative = false;
    }

    return ans;




}
```

Comment: There are a number of libraries that implement operations on large numbers. Google is down the hall, last door on your left.

Comment: Maybe look up how to do "long division". That divides numbers piece by piece.

Comment: I have searched a lot for that but I cant seem to find anything useful

Comment: Sam Varshavchik what would you recommend searching exactly?

Comment: First hit on google: https://www.mathsisfun.com/long_division.html

Comment: its treating the divisor just like i did in my program in that link

Comment: The Gnu MP library.